# Find dates and difference between extreme observations

Tags: pandas, function, extract

he function passed to apply must take a dataframe as its first argument and return a DataFrame, Series or scalar. apply will then take care of combining the results back together into a single dataframe or series. apply is therefore a highly flexible grouping method.

While apply is a very flexible method, its downside is that using it can be quite a bit slower than using more specific methods like agg or transform. Pandas offers a wide range of method that will be much faster than using apply for their specific purposes, so try to use them before reaching for apply.

Comment: Hi Diamy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of your data. Instead, provide the actual text of it. You can use three backticks (```) to surround the data for better formatting.

Comment: if you are looking for a function, what are you expecting? a list of all dates? Doesn't @oliver response provide you that information? Provide more details about what you expect as output from the function.

Answer (score 0):

easiest is an aggregation with `groupby` and then do a select

```
# make index a column
df = df.reset_index()                      

# get min of holdings for each ticker
lowest = df[['ticker','holdings']].groupby('ticker').min()
print(lowest)

# select lowest my performing a left join (solutions with original)
# this gives only the matching rows of df in return
lowest_dates = lowest.merge(df, on=['ticker','holdings'], how='left')
print(lowest_dates)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but we need to do it with a function:

Comment: def getLowest(df):

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a series of Date you can use this function.

```
def getLowest(df): 
    df = df.reset_index()
    lowest = df[['ticker','holdings']].groupby('ticker').min()
    lowest_dates = lowest.merge(df, on=['ticker','holdings'], how='left')
    return lowest_dates['Date']
```

From my point of view it would be better to return the entire dataframe, to know which ticker was lowest when. In this case you can :

```
return lowest_dates
```